# Laravel, How to use groupby to show product title and its related items

Tags: php, laravel

I'm very sorry for the way I wrote the question, I dont know exactly how to explain my issue but hope you will get what I want; I want to show a product and its add-ons, all working fine but I want to group these add-ons under their title, please see the screenshot you well get clear about my problem
so I want to stop repeat the similar titles .. I'm very new to laravel :(

[image]

For the tables: I have:

```
   class OrderCustomize extends Model
 {
protected $table = "ordercustomizes";

protected $fillable = [

    'customizeproduct_id',
    'userorder_id',
    'product_id'
];
```

Another Table:

```
 class CustomizeProduct extends Model
 {
protected $table = "customizeproducts";

protected $fillable = [

    'customizetitle_id',
    'product_id',
    'selection_type',
    'selection_number',
    'customize_title',
    'customize_price'
];
```

And this table:

```
 class CustomizeTitle extends Model
 {
protected $table = "customizetitles";

protected $fillable = [
    'name'

];
```

in controller:

```
$customizeorders = OrderCustomize::where('userorder_id',$order_number)
    ->with('customizeproduct')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('customizetitle_id');
```

in OrderCustomize model:

```
public function customizeproduct()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(CustomizeProduct::class);
}
```

in CustomizeProduct model:

```
public function customizetitle()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(CustomizeTitle::class);
}
```

in Blade:

```
@if(count($customizeorders)>0)
    @foreach ($customizeorders as $customizetitle => $groupCustomizes)
        @foreach($groupCustomizes as $key=>$customize) 
            @if(($userorder->product_id)==($customize->product_id))

               {{$customize->customizeproduct->customizetitle->name}}:
               {{$customize->customizeproduct->customize_title}} .

            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endif
```

dump data:

```
 Collection {#1554 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
"" => Collection {#1553 ▼
  #items: array:13 [▼    
    0 => OrderCustomize {#1485 ▶}
    1 => OrderCustomize {#1486 ▼
      #table: "ordercustomizes"
      #fillable: array:3 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 45
        "customizeproduct_id" => 153
        "userorder_id" => "36-ZA"
        "product_id" => 2618
        "created_at" => "2019-09-05 01:38:47"
        "updated_at" => "2019-09-05 01:38:47"
      ]
      #original: array:6 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvU0O.jpg

Comment: you can just work with collection you got. and for example join it with comma. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-join

Comment: I need a real solution, this is very complicated for me

Comment: show us your database structure and dump of your data you need to group. `dd($customizeorders)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent groupBy to return one title of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57882437/laravel-eloquent-groupby-to-return-one-title-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the below query for the concat the title:

```
$customizeorders = OrderCustomize::select( DB::raw ("GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT customizetitle_id) as customizetitle_ids") )
                   ->where('userorder_id',$order_number)
                   ->with('customizeproduct')->get();
```

Comment: As, I don't know about the structure so please check your database design and match the above code.

Comment: I hope you can help me more, what I have to change in your code to make it work with me?

Comment: Please share the tables with the relationships.

Comment: please help me, Im waiting for you to answer me after editing my question

Comment: As i have no much time i have generate the row query

Comment: SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT customize_title) as stuff  , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name) as title  FROM `ordercustomizes` as c 
left join  customizeproducts as p  on p.id = c.customizeproduct_id
left join customizetitles as t on t.id =  p.customizetitle_id
WHERE userorder_id = 1
GROUP By p.customizetitle_id

Comment: Please check the query