# Laravel Eloquent groupBy to return one title of each group

Tags: php, laravel

I have a very complex issue, I want to show items under one title if title is the same for every item, Im new to Laravel and dont know how to do this, I hope there is a real soution for this issue, below screen shot of the result, please help me in a very detailed solution to solve this issue, im suffering since a week to solve it but cant do this

```
 screen shot:
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfcPO.jpg

**Tables:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdBz5.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxpN9.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YweE.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g53ad.jpg

Controller:

```
 $customizeorders = OrderCustomize::where('userorder_id',$order_number)->with('customizeproduct')->get()->groupBy('customizetitle_id');
```

OrderCustomize Model:

```
  protected $table = "ordercustomizes";
     protected $fillable = [        
   'customizeproduct_id',
    'userorder_id',
    'product_id'
];

 public function customizeproduct()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(CustomizeProduct::class);
 }
```

CustomizeProduct Model:

```
  protected $table = "customizeproducts";

 protected $fillable = [

    'customizetitle_id',
    'product_id',
    'selection_type',
    'selection_number',
    'customize_title',
    'customize_price'
];

 public function customizetitle()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(CustomizeTitle::class);
 }
```

Blade:

```
  @if(count($customizeorders)>0)

  @foreach ($customizeorders as $customizetitle => $groupCustomizes)

@foreach($groupCustomizes as $key=>$customize) 

        @if(($userorder->product_id)==($customize->product_id))


    <div>{{$customize->customizeproduct->customizetitle->name}}:</div>

 {{$customize->customizeproduct->customize_title}} .


@endif
@endforeach         
@break
 @endforeach
  @endif
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: what output you expecting? whats the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```html
//you need to create array to store the array of items having same title.
//i guess the item having same title also have same id.
Then you should use order by id  not group by.
//it will provide you the data of same id in the conitnuous queue
//then you can use foreach loop to push the group of items in array and wrap that array with another array.
//so that you can push that in view. then you can loop through the array in view get the desired data.

//here in this method it have check if the items belongs to previous items or not using the $previousItem variable
public function show_device_report(Request $request)
    {
        //store the overall report.
        $wholeData = [];
        //stores the individual wrapper.
        $wrapper = [];
        //getting the id for the first items in the list
        $previousItem = $datas[0]->id;
        //transforming the values before sending to the view by
        foreach ($datas as $data) {
            //store the report of every items
            $singleItem = [];
            if ($data->id == $previousItem) {
                $id = $data->id
                //get all the item you need and push in the array.
                array_push($singleItem, $id, $name, $etc);
                array_push($wrapper, $singleItem);
            } else {
                $previousItem = $data->id;
                array_push($wholeData, $wrapper);
                //set the wrapper to null so that it can store the another items group in another index.
                $wrapper= [];
        }
        return $wholeData ;
    }
```

You need to modify little code according to your needs. As there is no any table structure provided by you.
store the individual item in singleItem[], then store all the single items in wraper[], and all the wraper[] in wholedata[]. Send wholedata[] to the view.

```
whole[
[wrapper1[item1,item2,item3]],
[wrapper2[item1,item2,item3,item4]],
[wrapper3[item1,item2]],
]
```

Comment: cant understand how to store and where to store in array?

Comment: I have added some hint for you. and also edited the answer

Comment: I have many tables I dont know how to store items from multi tables into array , can I provide you the tables?

Comment: I added the 4 tables that I use to display the titles and its items

Comment: you can use the collection object of your join query for retrieving data as an array,  then use the loop in that. Means after getting data in  $customizeorders variable, use the variable to operate the foreach loop

Comment: still cant understand how to store from multiple tables in array, did you see the tables?

Comment: @CHARITA SHRESTHA please see my question here, I applied your way but something doesnot work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895485/laravel-store-into-array-the-similar-items?noredirect=1#comment102212744_57895485

Comment: please I need your help