# Laravel, store into array the similar items

Tags: php, laravel

I have a very complex problem, I have products and modifiers, and also title of the modifiers, I want to store into array the title, product id and modifiers, the way of storing is if the title is the same and the product id the same then store into array and so on for others, after that I want in blade to display product id without repeat the same product id and under it the modifier title without repeat as if i want to use groupby and under the title to show the modifiers, I tried this code but it shows every title in one array, I hope you got what I need sorry for my bad language, please note that Im new to laravel so would be great if you help me to show the result in the blade view, thank you in adavance

```php
$customizeorders = OrderCustomize::where('userorder_id',$order_number)->with('customizeproduct')->get();

$wholeData = [];
$wrapper   = [];

$previousTitle   = $customizeorders[0]->customizeproduct->customizetitle->name;
$previousProduct = $customizeorders[0]->product_id;

foreach ($customizeorders as $data) {
    $singleItem = [];
    if ( ($data->customizeproduct->customizetitle->name == $previousTitle) AND ($data->product_id == $previousProduct) ) {
        $title     = $data->customizeproduct->customizetitle->name;
        $product   = $data->product_id;
        $modifiers = $data->customizeproduct->customize_title;

        array_push($singleItem, $title, $product, $modifiers);
        array_push($wrapper, $singleItem);
    } else {
        $previousTitle   = $data->customizeproduct->customizetitle->name;
        $previousProduct = $data->product_id;
        $modifiers       = $data->customizeproduct->customize_title;
        $title           = $data->customizeproduct->customizetitle->name;
        $product         = $data->product_id;
        $modifiers       = $data->customizeproduct->customize_title;

        array_push($singleItem, $title, $product, $modifiers);
        array_push($wrapper, $singleItem);
    }
    array_push($wholeData, $wrapper);
    $wrapper = [];
}
```

The result:

```
array:13 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "TELL US IF YOU'LL NEED"
      1 => 2606
      2 => "Napkins"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "ADD TOPPINGS"
      1 => 2610
      2 => "Sausage"
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "ADD TOPPINGS"
      1 => 2610
      2 => "Bacon"
    ]
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "ADD TOPPINGS"
      1 => 2610
      2 => "Onions"
    ]
  ]
  4 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "ADD TOPPINGS"
      1 => 2610
      2 => "Hot Giardiniera"
    ]
  ]
  5 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "ADD TOPPINGS"
      1 => 2610
      2 => "Garlic"
    ]
  ]
  6 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "ADD TOPPINGS"
      1 => 2610
      2 => "BBQ Sauce"
    ]
  ]
  7 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "SELECT SODA TYPES"
      1 => 2662
      2 => "Assorted Regular Sodas"
    ]
  ]
  8 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "ADD TOPPINGS"
      1 => 2618
      2 => "Grilled Chicken"
    ]
  ]
  9 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "ADD TOPPINGS"
      1 => 2618
      2 => "Anchovies"
    ]
  ]
  10 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "ADD TOPPINGS"
      1 => 2618
      2 => "Black Olives"
    ]
  ]
  11 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "ADD TOPPINGS"
      1 => 2618
      2 => "Pepperoni"
    ]
  ]
  12 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "TELL US IF YOU'LL NEED"
      1 => 2618
      2 => "Napkins"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Please explain the models involved and their relationships.

Comment: @IGP I think no need to show the relationships because its clear what I want to store exactly but here you can check the relationship https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57882437/laravel-eloquent-groupby-to-return-one-title-of-each-group/57883220?noredirect=1#comment102196006_57883220

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel, How to store items in array grouped by their title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57900465/laravel-how-to-store-items-in-array-grouped-by-their-title)